# Cordova Plugin VS2015 meta viewport user-scalable=yes not working

Tags: android, html, cordova, meta-tags

I'm new in Cordova and Html,CSS,JS, but after long time of searching threw the internet I did not find a suitable answer to my question.

So I created a Hybrid App in VS2015. It's a multi Page App... So On Startpage I have 3 Buttons, each navigates to a new Page and so on.
What I'm trying to do is to have one of these Pages using the Meta: `content="user-scalable=yes"` but its not working.
I tryed it in every constellation:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, minimum-scale=0.5, width=device-width">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, minimum-scale=0.5">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=1, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, minimum-scale=0.5">
<meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=2, minimum-scale=0.5">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

and so on....
Nothing works on Android. With Windows 10 Device it's working just fine.

I also added:

```
  <preference name='EnableViewportScale' value='true'/>
```

to `config.xml` but it's still not working.

Now I'm totally helpless what to try next.
Anyone knows a Solution for this Problem?

Comment: i am having this same issue, i tried everything i found online, settings.setUseWideViewPort(true); in MainActivity and in SystemWebViewEngine, nothing works, viewport is ignored in android

Answer (score 1):

You can try to simplify the meta tag and using only one line of meta

"< meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.5, maximum-scale=12.0, minimum-scale=.25, user-scalable=yes"/>"

Hope this can help to resolve the issue.